# Specific rules for writing an SDK for Android

Tags: android, sdk

Are there any specific rules to follow if I want to write an SDK for Android? Think the Paypal SDK or the Facebook SDK.

Comment: 1. Make it easy to integrate 2. Have good documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to think of an SDK as a way of creating a specific DSL for the problem your SDK is trying to solve. As such, creating an SDK (or an API, in the broader sense) is similar to creating a new language.

If this happens to be the way you look at the problem, check out the [keynote](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw) that Josh Bloch gave about API design. A lot of his advice applies to SDK design as well.

---

When it comes to the specific case of Android, there is one thing you have to keep in mind: **deployment**. [Deployment on Android sucks](http://jakewharton.com/the-android-build-system-is-broken/). Yes, we are in the phase of transitioning into gradle-based build system, but most projects are still either using Maven or are simply Eclipse projects. If you are to provide an SDK for Android, you pretty much have to support:

- People who want to use gradle: in such a case, you need to export your project in the **aar** format. More information about it [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Differences-between-a-Project-and-a-Library-Project)
- People who are still using Maven. In this case, you have to deploy your project on the Maven repository, using the Maven android plugin. More information [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/DeploymentInstructions)
- People who want to include your SDK as a library in Eclipse. This is similar to how Facebook describes it on their [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#import) Page.

There are ways to avoid so much duplication of deployment channels (providing the apklib from Maven unzipped as an Eclipse project, using Maven's aar support), but, until the build system matures, you will probably have to juggle between all three deployment paths.

**Hint**: You probably don't need to cover all three cases. To find out which deployment paths can be dropped, look at how your competitors are offering their SDK.

As for documentation, the minimum Javadocs are required. You could, however, be creative, and try [Parse.com's style of API guide](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide), which reads very nicely.